# Elasticsearch custom analyzer randomly crashing on numeric value

Tags: elasticsearch, lexical-analysis

I have a cluster of three nodes, configured to have three shards and 2 replicas.
I created a custom analyzer named "name" with the following definition :

```
"analyzer": {
  "name": {
    "tokenizer": "lowercase",
    "filter": [
      "base_elision",
      "name_synonym",
      "unique_tokens"
    ],
    "char_filter": [
      "acronym_filter"
    ]
  }
}
```

It is part of a mapping that applies to `myIndex`.

When I call

```
POST myIndex/_analyze 
{
  "analyzer": "name",
  "text":    "90000175",
  "explain": true
}
```

It randomly gives me a 500 error (I'd say around 2 out of 3 times, but I haven't made any stats).

```
{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "null_pointer_exception",
        "reason": null
      }
    ],
    "type": "null_pointer_exception",
    "reason": null
  },
  "status": 500
}
```

When it does answer, the response is empty :

```
{
  "detail" : {
    "custom_analyzer" : true,
    "charfilters" : [
      {
        "name" : "acronym_filter",
        "filtered_text" : [
          "90000175"
        ]
      }
    ],
    "tokenizer" : {
      "name" : "lowercase",
      "tokens" : [ ]
    },
    "tokenfilters" : [
      {
        "name" : "base_elision",
        "tokens" : [ ]
      },
      {
        "name" : "name_synonym",
        "tokens" : [ ]
      },
      {
        "name" : "unique_tokens",
        "tokens" : [ ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

In addition, it works perfectly fine if the `text` value is not numeric (eg : "90000175a"). With that exemple, I would get all documents that contain `a`, the numeric part is ignored.

Edit :

```
"char_filter": {
  "acronym_filter": {
    "type": "pattern_replace",
    "pattern": "(?<=([\\. ][a-z])|(^[a-z]))[\\. ]+(?=([a-z][\\. ])|([a-z]$))",
    "replacement": ""
  }
}

"base_elision": {
  "type": "elision",
  "articles": [
    "l",
    "m",
    "t",
    "qu",
    "n",
    "s",
    "j",
    "d",
    "c"
  ]
}

"name_synonym": {
  "type": "synonym",
  "lenient": true,
  "synonyms": [
    "mairie, commune, ville",
    "etab => etablissement",
    "ets => etablissement, entreprise",
    "ste, soc, societe",
    "exploi, exploitation",
    "electricite de france => electricite de france, edf",
    "pdts, produits"
  ]
}

"unique_tokens": {
  "type": "unique"
}
```

Comment: Can you share the definition of `acronym_filter`? If you remove all replica shards, does it also error out?

Comment: @Val I added the filter's definition. I'll see with the admins if we can remove the replicas

Comment: Thanks, what about `base_elision`?

Comment: @Val I edited the post to put the base_elision definition

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot `name_synonym` and `unique_tokens` too... otherwise there's no way for me to recreate your index

Comment: @val done, i've completed the definition :)

Comment: Interesting... seems to be a bug somewhere. I'll investigate, but feel free to [report it](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues) if you think so as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was indeed a bug that was fixed in `6.8.2`.